# why does webpack 4 include the whole file for single named import?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, tree-shaking

Given the following two files :

```js
//a.js
export const X = /*#__PURE__*/ "X";

const a = function () {
  return "About a!";
};
a.foo = function () {
  return "foo";
};
export default a;
```

and

```js
//main.js
import { X } from "./a";
import { Y } from "./b";

console.log(X, Y);
```

I have added

- `"sideEffect": false` to `package.json`
- `optimization.usedExports: true` to `webpack.config.js`

but running `webpack -p` still includes the whole `a.js` file in the bundle. Rollup only includes `X` from `a.js` ([demo](https://rollupjs.org/repl/?version=2.12.1&shareable=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))

Removing the `a.foo` definition "fixes" the issue but is not a solution outside the demo repository. 
I have read the [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) documentation page multiple times, read [countless issues about tree shaking on the webpack issue tracker, I still cant figure out the following :

- Why is the `/*#__PURE__*/` marker on `X` not being used ?
- Is there a way to configure webpack to only include X from `a.js` ?

You can also checkout the [sandbox repository](https://github.com/jeantil/next-bugs/tree/bug/incorrect_tree_shaking) to see the full webpack configuration and the corresponding next.js/react issue (see pages/index.jsx) which led me to this specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After raising the [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11042) on webpack's issue tracker [~sokra](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11042#issuecomment-644237555) provided an answer:

> Seems like a single compression pass in terser is not enough to compress this code.

The default number of passes is 1 but once raised to 3, `a.js` is no longer fully inlined. This is how this can be achieved at the cost of a longer build time.

```
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

/** @type {import("webpack").Configuration} */
module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserWebpackPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    compress: {
                        passes: 3
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess: `export default` affects tree shaking.
See: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/javascript-tree-shaking-like-a-pro-7bf96e139eb7#43e1

Try not remove the `default`.

Comment: As mentionned in my question, if I remove the `a.foo=` definition the default export is correctly tree-shaken. Also whether with or without the `a.foo` definition, the export is correctly marked as `/* unused harmony default export */`

Comment: the article is interesting, I will look into the plugins it recommends

Comment: both techniques described in the article fail to detect a tree shaking failure which would explain the full inlining of a.js